# How to append an array in another array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

I have a JSON response whose answer I have to parse. I write the single elements into an array called `courseDataArray` using a `for loop`. After that, I want to write this newly created array into another array called `combinedCourseArray` with the aim to pass that on to a `UITableView`. Creating the first array seems to work fine.

But how can I create another array `combinedCourseArray` who contain all arrays of type `courseDataArray`?

```
for (index, element) in result.enumerate() {

            // get one entry from the result array
            if let courseEntry = result[index] as? [String:AnyObject]{

                //work with the content of the array
                let courseName = courseEntry["name"]
                let courseType = courseEntry["course_type"]
                let courseDate = courseEntry["cor_date"]
                let courseId = courseEntry["cor_id"]
                let duration = courseEntry["duration"]
                let schoolId = courseEntry["sco_id"]
                let status = courseEntry["status"]


                let courseDataArray = ["courseName" : courseName, "courseType": courseType, "courseDate": courseDate, "courseId": courseId, "duration": duration, "schoolId":schoolId, "status":status]

                print(courseDataArray)

                var combinedCourseArray: [String: AnyObject] = [:]
                combinedCourseArray[0] = courseDataArray //does not work -- error: cannot subscript a value of type...

               // self.shareData.courseStore.append(scooter)

            }
```

Comment: `combinedArray` should be of type `[[String: AnyObject]]` as it is an `Array<[String:AnyObject]>`. Use `var combinedCourseArray: [[String: AnyObject]] = [[:]]`

Comment: `[String: AnyObject]` is dictionary not array

Comment: Thx. that was the problem. I had to add ? after AnyObject: var combinedCourseArray: [[String: AnyObject?]] = [[:]]

Comment: BTW, `courseDataArray` is actually a `Dictionary` not an `Array`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should move the combinedCourseArray declaration outside of the array. It should be `var combinedCourseArray: [[String: AnyObject]] = [[:]]` since it's an array and not a dictionary.

And you should be doing

```
combinedCourseArray.append(courseDataArray)
```

instead of

```
combinedCourseArray[0] = courseDataArray
```

Comment: Thx. works fine. I had to add the question mark here: var combinedCourseArray: [[String: AnyObject?]] = [[:]]

Answer (score 5):

```
var FirstArray = [String]()
var SecondArray = [String:AnyObject]()

FirstArray.append(contentsOf: SecondArray.value(forKey: "key") as! [String])
```

Answer (score 3):

First declare this `combinedCourseArray` array out side this loop

```
var combinedCourseArray: [[String: AnyObject]] = [[String: AnyObject]]()
for (index, element) in result.enumerate() {

        // get one entry from the result array
        if let courseEntry = result[index] as? [String:AnyObject]{

            //work with the content of the array
            let courseName = courseEntry["name"]
            let courseType = courseEntry["course_type"]
            let courseDate = courseEntry["cor_date"]
            let courseId = courseEntry["cor_id"]
            let duration = courseEntry["duration"]
            let schoolId = courseEntry["sco_id"]
            let status = courseEntry["status"]


            let courseDataArray = ["courseName" : courseName, "courseType": courseType, "courseDate": courseDate, "courseId": courseId, "duration": duration, "schoolId":schoolId, "status":status]

            print(courseDataArray)


            combinedCourseArray.append(courseDataArray) //does not work -- error: cannot subscript a value of type...

           // self.shareData.courseStore.append(scooter)

        }
 }
```

Comment: Thx. works fine. I had to add the question mark here: var combinedCourseArray: [[String: AnyObject?]] = [[:]]

Answer (score 1):

Just use `flatMap` on the outer array to translate one array into another array, possibly dropping some elements:

```
let courseDataArray : [[String:AnyObject?]] = result.flatMap {
    guard let courseEntry = $0 as? [String:AnyObject] else {
        return nil
    }

    return [
        "courseName" : courseEntry["name"],
        "courseType": courseEntry["course_type"],
        "courseDate": courseEntry["cor_date"],
        "courseId": courseEntry["cor_id"],
        "duration": courseEntry["duration"],
        "schoolId": courseEntry["sco_id"],
        "status": courseEntry["status"]
    ]
}
```

Of course, the guard isn't really necessary since the input type is presumably already `[[String:AnyObject]]` and since you then can't have any internal failures, you can just use `map` instead of `flatMap`