# How to limit array to show 5 items and on button click load 5 more

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, nsarray

I have an array of comments, but I only want to show 5 comments.
On click load more comments i want show previous 5 comments + 5 new comments.

Getting comments from api

```
if  let arr : NSArray = responseData as? NSArray {

    self?.arrComments = NSMutableArray()

    if arr.count != 0{

        self?.arrComments = arr.mutableCopy() as? NSMutableArray ?? []

        self?.tblView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

dequeue tableView cell

```
if arrComments.count != 0 {
    if let myDict: NSDictionary = arrComments.object(at: indexPath.row) as? NSDictionary {        
        cell.lblComment.text = string(myDict, "Comment")
        cell.lblTime.text =  string(myDict, "CommentDate")
```

Comment: Are you getting all comments at once or you are getting 5 at a time from API ? Also stop using `NS`-classes in `Swift` as much as possible.

Comment: I'm getting 5 comments at a time from api.

Comment: So you send lastIndex or something to your API to load more comments right?

Comment: Yes I'm sending last index.

Comment: Take 2 arrays, one will hold the data for `UITableView` (say `commentsArray` ) and another one just to hold the data from `API` response ( say `responseArray` ). Then `append` all the elements of `responseArray` to `commentsArray` instead of `assigning` `responseArray` to `commentsArray`. Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38617976/how-to-append-an-array-in-another-array-in-swift

Comment: Don't use `NS(Mutable)...` collection types in Swift. Use native types and with `var` you get mutability for free.